# Bootstrap fullscreen width responsive Carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make my slider width to screenwidth instead i have some padding from left and right side and it looks ugly.Searched something and all i found is Jquery plugins i was thinking is there a bootstrap class already made to apply and make things happen or some css modifications.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="col-md-12">                 
                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                    <!-- Indicators -->
                                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
                                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="6"></li>
                                    </ol>                                   
                                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                                    <div class="carousel-inner"  role="listbox">

                                        <div class="item active">
                                            ...
                                        </div>  

                                        <div class="item">
                                            ...
                                        </div>  

                                        <div class="item">
                                            ...
                                        </div>                                  
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Left and right controls -->
                                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With bootstrap, you have to create a .row div between .col-md and .container-fluid. It will remove the 15px padding created by .col-md

Or you can simply add a custom class and apply a padding: 0 on it.

Answer (score 0):

Just do not use bootstrap classes when there is no point to, replace .container-fluid with just a block element with margin auto;
or you can use a .row class which has negative x margins to create a socket parent for the nested padded element.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following rule to your css file:

```
.container-fluid {
  padding: 0px !important;
}
```

And wrap your col-md-12 with .row div for ex:

```
...
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
   ...
```